# Custom Wordpress Theme don't break the paragraph

Tags: wordpress-theming

Paragraph don't break the line in my custom template.
I'm a beginner and I've tried to change the style of 'p'.

[image]

Comment: What style of the p element have you changed? Are you sure your CSS [selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) are targeting the the p element correctly. Looks like you p elements [display property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) is set to inline and not block.

Comment: .blog-post p {word-wrap: break-all; display: block; width:560px;}

Comment: I got it, I used the "word-break: break-word;"